# Cache gets null when I try to retrieve information in another class method

Tags: c#, caching

I'm trying to use cache to save some information for later use. This is how I assign cache:

```
foreach(MibGet Device in DeviceValuesList)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[DeviceID] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache[DeviceID] = DeviceValue;
    }
}
```

I can see in the debugger that this code works absolutely fine, all the data I want is assigned properly. But when I try to retrieve this information from the cache like this (From another class method):

```
if (NewValue != HttpContext.Current.Cache[DeviceID].ToString())
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache[DeviceID] = NewValue;
}
```

It throws a null reference exception. In the debugger It show that `HttpContext.Current` is null. What could be the problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is null when there is no current `HttpContext`. ASP.NET uses one thread per request model. It creates an instance of `HttpContext` and associates it to the thread that process the request. But if you create a thread, explicitly o implicitly by using tasks or async programming, it might not be associated with an `HttpContext`

I suggest you using some other cache classes such as `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` that are not tied to an `HttpContext`.

Comment: The program indeed has multiple threads. That might be the problem. I'll try the cache class you said

Comment: Do you know any good documentation, or have a clear example for how can I use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze, MemoryCache is very simple. Here you have a simple example: https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/15309/memorycache

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your cache is a dictionary. Then instead of

```
if (get.Value != HttpContext.Current.Cache[get.DeviceID.ToString()].ToString())
```

you should write

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Cache.ContainsKey(get.DeviceID))
```

Also in your first code snippet you put `Device.Value` in the cache, but in the second snippet you put `DeviceID`. I can't see how that'd work.

Comment: "get" is an object, which has properties "DeviceID" and "Value". I need to check if get's new value is different from an older value. The only problem here is that when I try to retrieve cached data "HttpContext.Current" is already null, despite is was set few seconds ago. I need to find out why it gets null

Comment: Well, that's difficult to answer without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I've edited my code to make it more simple and clear to understand